# Union 2 tables have same structure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have 2 tables with same structure ex: `Table1(Timestamp, Value)` and `Table2(Timestamp, Value)`. I want union 2 these tables as a table like: `Table3(Timestamp, Value1, Value2)` where `Value1 is value of Table1` and `Value2 is value of Table2`. How can I do that on SQL Server?

Comment: Read about [Join (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Timestamp,
    Table1.Value as Value1
    Table2.Value as Value2
FROM
    Table1
    Left join Table2
        on Table1.Timestamp = Table2.Timestamp

UNION

SELECT
    Table1.Timestamp,
    Table1.Value as Value1
    Table2.Value as Value2
FROM
    Table1
    RIGHT join Table2
        on Table1.Timestamp = Table2.Timestamp  
WHERE       Table1.Timestamp IS NULL
```

Comment: I like it, with this solution i can create dynamic query with n table unions

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (TS int, Value int);
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (TS int, Value int);

DECLARE @table3 TABLE(TS int, Value1 int, Value2 int);


INSERT INTO @table1(TS, Value)
SELECT 1, 12
UNION SELECT 3, 34
UNION SELECT 9, 122

INSERT INTO @table2(TS, Value)
SELECT 1, 23
UNION SELECT 2, 99
UNION SELECT 3, 999
UNION SELECT 5, 1222
```

-- ANSWER: --

```
INSERT INTO @table3(TS, Value1, Value2)
SELECT ISNULL(t1.TS, t2.TS), t1.Value, T2.Value
FROM @table1 t1
FULL JOIN @table2 t2 ON t2.TS = t1.TS

SELECT * FROM @table3
ORDER BY TS
```

Example code above. Change TS to preferred name and data type

Comment: This is my interpretation of the question as well.  I would add `as TS` so the first column has an appropriate name.

Comment: Perfect! But, how about if i want extend to 3 or n tables

Answer (score 0):

Join this two tables:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Timestamp,
    Table1.Value as Value1
    Table2.Value as Value2
FROM
    Table1
    inner join Table2
        on Table1.Timestamp = Table2.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use UNION?

```
select TS, value as value1, NULL as value2 FROM T1
UNION
select TS, NULL, value as value2 from T2
```

This should work in most DBMSs.

Comment: This probably will not merge the records using the time stamps.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed why don't you think so?

Comment: When TS is the same, but Values are different, they will come in two records instead of one.

Comment: I assume that if one tuple in T1 has values a,b and one tuple in T2 has values a,c. The I would expect that a,c and a,c would be part of the result. if T1 and T2 have both a,b, then only one a,b would be in the result. I thought that was what the poster wanted.